# Is it possible to executive Trigger before the lead assignment rules?

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, before-trigger

I Just want to know is there any way that we can executive trigger before the lead assignment rules.

My Case:

I have one before insert trigger in the lead, here in this trigger I'm checking company name with Existing Accounts, if it equals then I'm assigning the lead owner equals to the account owner.

Above my case is only for the one country

Problem: we are following the web to lead the process for the leads in this case lead assignment rules are executing first, because of this I can't able to assign based on Account Owner.

Answer (score 1):

We can do that using the **Future** method. Simply you can write your code in the future method . It may be resolved your problem.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Hi Piyush,
Thanks for your reply.
I need some reference for this.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm

Comment: Hi Piyush,
Do you think is it fine to use the `@future` method in the above case(My Case).

Comment: Yes, I guess it works on your condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the complete Order of Execution here:

[Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

> 3. Executes all before triggers. 
>      ...
> 4. Executes assignment rules. 
>      ...
> 5. If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and
>      only one more time), in addition to standard validations. Custom
>      validation rules, duplicate rules, and escalation rules are not run
>      again.

Maybe there's your problem...

Comment: (should be 3, 8, 12, but my counting get's messed up.)

Comment: Hi Tiruman,
Thanks for your reply.
I know where is my problem, I'm looking for the solution.